# Lambda function argument + deduction improvement

Tags: c++, lambda, type-deduction

I constructed this template function for a double for loop that has to be executed a lot and used to be done with a macro:

```
template <typename TYPE_OF_ENTITY, typename LAMBDA_FUNC>
void foreach_t(list faces, LAMBDA_FUNC func)
{
    for(...)
        for(...)
            func(pEnt)
}
```

This worked really well and could be called:

```
foreach_t<FACE>(faces,[&](FACE* pFace){...});
```

Then I wanted to enfore that your lambda has to have TYPE_OF_ENTITY* as an argument. For this I needed a statefull and stateless template function.

```
template <typename TYPE_OF_ENTITY, typename LAMBDA_RETURN_TYPE>
using functionPtr = LAMBDA_RETURN_TYPE(*)(TYPE_OF_ENTITY*);

template <typename TYPE_OF_ENTITY, typename LAMBDA_RETURN_TYPE>
void foreach_t(list faces, functionPtr<TYPE_OF_ENTITY, LAMBDA_RETURN_TYPE> func)
{
    for(...)
        for(...)
            func(pEnt)
}

template <typename TYPE_OF_ENTITY, typename LAMBDA_RETURN_TYPE>
void foreach_t(list faces, std::function<LAMBDA_RETURN_TYPE(TYPE_OF_ENTITY*)> func)
{
    for(...)
        for(...)
            func(pEnt)
}
```

They work as I want, only now I have to specify the 2 template arguments since they can't be deduced anymore:

```
foreach_t<FACE, void>(faces,[&](FACE* pFace){...});
```

Is there a way to improve this deduction so I only need to pass the function arguments?

If possible it needs to be supported by the [visual studio 2013 compatible v2.1 compiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you need to do is to check if lambda takes value of type `TYPE_OF_ENTITY*` as parameter you don't really need to split function into two separate overloads (for statefull and stateless lambda). You could simply check if it can be called with this kind of parameter e.g.:

```
#include <type_traits> // for std::declval

template <typename TYPE_OF_ENTITY, typename LAMBDA_FUNC>
auto foreach_t(list faces, LAMBDA_FUNC func) -> decltype(func(std::declval<TYPE_OF_ENTITY*>()), void())
{
    for(...)
        for(...)
            func(pEnt)
}
```

Comment: Upon searching further I just found declval was a thing, gonna test this and try to understand it.

Comment: I'm gonna do some experimentation with this to understand it better but can you explain what your code does some more. I know the -> decltype construction is to specify the return type of auto.
I suspect func(std::declval<TYPE_OF_ENTITY*>()) is the calling with TYPE_OF_ENTITY* and void() is the return type but I do not see how this comes together to enforce the correct return type.
What if it the lambda return something else than void, doesn't that introduce an error in my function because it does not return anything?

Comment: Yup - this kind of return type declaration is called trailing return type. It is SFINAE friendly which means if there will be another overload that takes different type of parameters it will be silently disclaimed in case if the other overload suits better. `decltype` triggers the sfinae and is to test if the expression in it is proper. An expression that is tested here is `func(std::declval<TYPE_OF_ENTITY*>())` so if the func can be called with value of type `TYPE_OF_ENTITY*`, `void()` is to preserve return type of `foreach_t` (void)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to specify the closure's return type at the point of function invocation, then `static_assert` could be helpful:

```
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

struct Dog {};

struct list {};

template <
typename LAMBDA_RETURN_TYPE,
  typename TYPE_OF_ENTITY, 
class F
>
void foreach_t(const std::vector<TYPE_OF_ENTITY*>& faces, F func)
{
  using ret_type = decltype(func(std::declval<TYPE_OF_ENTITY*>()));
  using same_type = typename std::is_same<LAMBDA_RETURN_TYPE, ret_type>::type;
  constexpr auto ok = same_type::value;
  static_assert(ok, "");
  for(auto pdog : faces)
    func(pdog);
}

int main()
{
  auto mydog = [](Dog* pdog) -> bool // change to int and this compiles
  { return false; };

  std::vector<Dog*> dogs;
  foreach_t<int>(dogs, mydog);  

}
```

Comment: This does seem to decrease the number of template arguments as I wanted but @W.F. 's answer seems to do the same in a more complicated but shorter way.
Do you think this answer has an advantage over the other one?

Comment: @turoni there is a difference. His is using SFNAE, mine is explicitly causing the program to fail if you pass a closure who's return type is different to that specified. The fact that I have spelled out the type checking line by line is just a matter of style. Which avenue you take will depend on your exact requirements.